# How to add tooltips or overlay text in a Matlab figure

Tags: matlab, tooltip, overlay, matlab-figure, mouseover

I have a figure with two or more lines. These lines have additional, important information associated with them, like how many data points were averaged to create the line etc. I would like to access this information in my figure.

I thought a good solution for this would be to if you could hover over a line with your mouse and get that extended information.

However searching for tooltips/overlays/hover-over on figures seemed to not be fruitful.

Example:

```
figure; hold on;
plot(1:10,rand(10,1))
plot(1:10,rand(10,1))
% additional info
plot_1_info.name = 'Alice';
plot_2_info.name = 'Bob';
plot_1_info.age = 24;
plot_2_info.age = 12;
```

Any good solutions or better approaches for this?

Comment: 2 questions: 1) Which MATLAB version are you using? 2) Are UIFigures an option for you?

Comment: 1) R2018b Update3, newest stable if I'm correct 2) I don't know about them I think, but I'd prefer as-simple-as-possible-approach

Comment: 1) Newest stable is R2019a ;) 2) It's just as simple... more a question of compatibility with existing code/figures (uifigures are the "new" figures).

Comment: both answers are awesome, chose Wolfie's one for backcompatibility, both should be right

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the [new data tip customization system introduced in R2019a](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html?rntext=&startrelease=R2019a&endrelease=R2019a&groupby=release&sortby=descending#mw_f3339c68-a89c-4961-8a50-b16957920f31), we can do the following:

```matlab
figure(); hP = plot(1:10,rand(10,1),1:10,rand(10,1));
nPts = cellfun(@numel, {hP.XData});
hP(1).DataTipTemplate.DataTipRows(end+1) = dataTipTextRow('Name', repmat("Alice",nPts(1),1) );
hP(1).DataTipTemplate.DataTipRows(end+1) = dataTipTextRow('Age',  repmat(12,     nPts(1),1) );
hP(2).DataTipTemplate.DataTipRows(end+1) = dataTipTextRow('Name', repmat("Bob",  nPts(2),1) );
hP(2).DataTipTemplate.DataTipRows(end+1) = dataTipTextRow('Age',  repmat(24,     nPts(2),1) );
% (Of course the above can be organized in a nicer way using a function)
```

Which yields:

[image]

Notice that the "hover datatip" has black text, while the "click datatip" has blue text - this is default behavior.

Comment: I think I understand the script, but it's quite complicated. I presume, using my example, I could go for `hP=findall(gcf,'type','axes')` and the thing would work the same?

Comment: Almost - `hP=findall(gcf,'type','Line')`.

Comment: Could you add/edit that it is necessary to convert `char`'s into `string` for this to work with Alice and Bob?

Comment: this ended up as simplest solution for me

Answer (score 6):

You can change the data cursor behaviour, this option has good backwards compatability (I've tested the below in R2017b, used similar before in 15b).

[image: data cursor]

See my comments for details:

```
% Create some data
x = (1:2:20).';
y = rand(10,1);
name = { 'Alice'; 'Alice'; 'Alice'; 'Alice'; 'Bob'; 'Bob'; 'Bob'; 'Chris'; 'Chris'; 'Chris' };
age = [ 24; 24; 24; 24; 12; 12; 12; 17; 17; 17 ];
% Put it in a table, so we have it all together for indexing as plot data
tbl = table( x, y, name, age );

% Create the plot, assign the UserData property to the plot object
f = figure; 
plt = plot( x, y );
plt.UserData = tbl;

% Hijack the Data Cursor update callback so we can inject our own info
dcm = datacursormode( f );
set( dcm, 'UpdateFcn', @onDataCursor );

% Function which returns the text to be displayed on the data cursor
function txt = onDataCursor( ~, evt )
    % Get containing figure
    f = ancestor( evt.Target, 'figure' );
    % Get the index within the original data
    idx = getfield( getCursorInfo( datacursormode( f ) ), 'DataIndex' );
    % The original data is stored in the UserData property
    data = evt.Target.UserData;
    % Each element of the cell array is a new line on the cursor
    txt = { sprintf( 'X: %g', data.x(idx) ), ...
            sprintf( 'Y: %g', data.y(idx) ), ...
            sprintf( 'Name: %s', data.name{idx} ), ...
            sprintf( 'Age: %g', data.age(idx) ) };          
end
```

Output:

[image: plot with data tip]

Note: I've not handled anywhere the case that there is more than one data cursor tip. You can easily implement a loop over `idx` within the callback to handle this, I leave it as an exercise.

---

This approach is really flexible. For instance if we had 3 lines (one per 'person') then they can each have their own `UserData` struct, and we don't need to repeat all the info in table rows.

```
A = struct( 'X', 1:4, 'Y', rand(1,4), 'Name', 'Alice', 'Age', 24 );
B = struct( 'X', 1:3, 'Y', rand(1,3), 'Name', 'Bob', 'Age', 12 );
C = struct( 'X', 1:3, 'Y', rand(1,3), 'Name', 'Chris', 'Age', 17 );

f = figure; hold on;
plt = plot( A.X, A.Y ); plt.UserData = A;
plt = plot( B.X, B.Y ); plt.UserData = B;
plt = plot( C.X, C.Y ); plt.UserData = C;

% ... Now the struct fields can be accessed from the callback
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that [in R2019a customizing datatips was greatly simplified](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html?rntext=&startrelease=R2019a&endrelease=R2019a&groupby=release&sortby=descending#mw_f3339c68-a89c-4961-8a50-b16957920f31).

Comment: @Dev-iL Feel free to post an answer, I've only got up to R2017b for testing, and the OP doesn't have R2019a.

Comment: thanks for this answer I will try it. @Dev-iL: I'm upgrading right now, please do post your answe :)